# How to convert string that represent json value to json

Tags: json, jolt

I have a string field that represents JSON value

```json
{ "value": "[{\"field_1\": \"123\",\"field_2\": \"id\",\"field_3\": \"qwe\"}]" }
```

Is there a way in jolt to convert it to JSON, something like this

```json
{ "value": [{"field_1": "123","field_2": "id","field_3": "qwe"}] }
```

I know format of objects in array, there always will be only three fields with same names, but the number of objects can vary

Also i wounder is there a way to do the opposite thing, like convert array to string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use successive **split** and **join** functions as in the following specification considering the fact

*there always will be only three fields with same names, but the number of objects can vary* :

```json
[
  { // generate an array, namely "value", with contents of each array which are purified from \" characters
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "val_0": "=split(\",@(1,value))",
      "val_1": "=join('',@(1,val_0))",
      "val_2": "=split('\\[\\{',@(1,val_1))",
      "val_3": "=join('',@(1,val_2))",
      "val_4": "=split('\\}\\]',@(1,val_3))",
      "val_5": "=join('',@(1,val_4))",
      "value": "=split('\\},\\{',@(1,val_5))"
    }
  },
  { // dissipate each components of the "value" array to form a new array of objects
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "value": {
        "*": {
          "@": "[&1].val"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // make "value" array with key-value-key-value-key-value ordered components 
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "v": "=split(',',@(1,val))",
        "val": "=join(':',@(1,v))",
        "value": "=split(':',@(1,val))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@(0,value[1])": "[#2].@(1,value[0])", // represents the key-value pair for "field_1"
        "@(0,value[3])": "[#2].@(1,value[2])", // represents the key-value pair for "field_2"
        "@(0,value[5])": "[#2].@(1,value[4])" // represents the key-value pair for "field_3"
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of the leading whitespaces of the values
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "=trim"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

{ "value": "[{"field_1": "123","field_2": "id"}]" }
you can try this text ,  because your text missing a character " { "